# Load AngularJS page/controller inside a Blazor Razor Page

Tags: c#, angularjs, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

My team has a nice-sized AngularJS app that we would like to modernize using Blazor webassembly, and I had assumed that there should be no problem loading a AngularJS controller and page if all the relevant javascript libraries were loaded.

I have successfully gotten everything integrated in a way that I "thought" would work, with the

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
```

on the blazor index.html page

and trying to load our basic search via a razor page and the ng-controller tag.

```
@page "/search"

<div ng-controller="searchCtrl as ctrl">
```

Amazingly all the angularjs code and libraries seem to load properly and I get no errors in the console.  The problem comes when I go to the /search page and AngularJS doesn't seem to recognize the ng-controller tag as the controller itself does not load.

I'm digging into the actual under-the-hood way that blazor deals with javascript libraries but my guess is that angular is loaded but not attached to the "real" DOM and its not getting the events that would let it know that a new page has been loaded.

Note that we are NOT using the angularjs router, but angularjs is supposed to work fine loading the controllers dynamically just from the ng-controller tag.

Anybody have any ideas on things I could try?

Comment: Update: I have been able to get a controller to load but only by putting the ng-controller attribute on the top-level with the ng-app.  It seems after the initial load angularjs is not aware of dom changes.  If another page adds a div with a new ng-controller tag its not loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

**add to the body of index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reinitAngular() {
        var injector = $('[ng-app]').injector();
        var $compile = injector.get('$compile');
        var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
        $compile(this.$el)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }
</script>
```

**within your Razor page/component add:**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

...

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("reinitAngular");
        }
    }
}
```

this will call our js function, which in turn should cause Angular to re-initialize itself. It probably needs to rescan the DOM which was changed by Blazor's own view switching.

Comment: I've got the JS code triggering but the this.$el element is null.

Finding values for injector, $compile and $rootScope.  Not seeing an error in the console, but i'm betting that this.$el should have something.

Comment: For reference i'm putting a repo out there with what i'm trying: https://github.com/ExcaliburVT/BlazorAngluarJS

Comment: Its timing now.  I avoided use of the this.$el and am just using $('[ng-app]')  If you place a button on the page and execute reinitAngular() from it the page compiles and works.  Just have to figure out how to delay the compile.

Comment: Success!  The key was to shift the re-init to OnAfterRenderAsync()
If you can update your example to reflect the code I put in the git repo I will give you credit.

Comment: ```
function reinitAngular() {
    console.log('reinitAngular called');
    var injector = $('[ng-app]').injector();
    var $compile = injector.get('$compile');
    var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
    var appElement = $('[ng-app]');
    $compile(appElement)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
}
```
```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

...
@code {
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("reinitAngular");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ExcaliburVT cool, thanks for the update I'm sorry I couldn't respond earlier as I'm actually on vacation, but your question raised my attention :)

Comment: I know this is an old question but I'm just coming across it now. Trying to get this working myself and $('[ng-app]').injector(); returns null for me every time. Any help on why?

Comment: @ChrisSearles at first i've set the ng-app="..." directive in a random div and i've got the same error as you; then moved it to <body> element and worked just fine. If anyone knos why, please let me know because i don't like to angular bootstrap the whole body.

Comment: Based on this thread i've managed to load the angularjs app, thanks! @ExcaliburVT, it's possible to use Blazor components inside the angular app? https://github.com/danmihaipatrascu/BlazorComponentIntegration in .../wwwroot/routedemo/third.html there's a Component1 reference that doesn't render.

Comment: @DanMihaiPatrascu i don't think its possible to use blazor inside angular.  The blazor elements are all generated on-the-fly.  I could be wrong but that was the opposite use case from what I developed above and have not attempted.